# Erro na inserção de dados no SQLServer + Delphi

Tags: sql-server, delphi

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao tentar cadastrar um novo registro no banco de dados ele me apresenta o seguinte erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

abaixo segue os codigos:

abrir o form para cadastro.

```
procedure TFMHome.lbl_IncOSClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
UDM.ADODSOs.Open;
UDM.ADODSPecas_ordem_servico.Open;
UDM.ADODSOs.Insert;
UDM.ADODSOsData_Abertura.AsDateTime:= Date;
UDM.ADODSOs.Post;
UDM.ADODSOs.Edit;
FMOs.showmodal;
end;
```

Inclusão do registro:

```
procedure TFMOs.Image1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
UDM.ADODSOs.Post;
 Application.MessageBox(
'O registro foi incluido com sucesso.',
'Informação',MB_OK+MB_ICONINFORMATION);
//end;
end;
```

Banco de Dados:

```
create table pecas (
ID_Peca int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
Nome varchar (50)NOT NULL,
Categoria varchar (20),
Unidade char (8),
Quantidade int NOT NULL,
Valor_Custo float NOT NULL,
Valor_Venda float NOT NULL,
Observacao varchar (max),
ID_Fornecedor INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES fornecedor (ID_Fornecedor)
)

create table veiculo (
ID_Veiculo int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
Placa varchar (15),
Modelo varchar (20),
Ano char (4),
Combustivel varchar (12),
Cor varchar (20),
N_Chassi varchar (30)NOT NULL,
Observacao varchar (max),
ID_CLIENTE INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES cliente (ID_CLIENTE)
)

create table ordem_servico(
ID_OrdemServico int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
Situacao varchar (20),
Km varchar (20),
Localizacao varchar (30),
Data_Abertura datetime,
Data_Fechamento datetime,
ID_Funcionario INT  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES funcionario (ID_Funcionario),
ID_Cliente INT  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES cliente (ID_Cliente),
ID_Peca INT  FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES pecas (ID_Peca),
ID_Veiculo INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES veiculo (ID_Veiculo)
)

create table pecas_ordem_servico(
ID_PECAS_ORDEMSERVICO int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,
ID_PECA INT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES PECAS (ID_peca),
ID_OrdemServico int NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES ordem_servico (ID_OrdemServico),
Valor_Unit float NOT NULL,
Qtde int NOT NULL,
Total float NOT NULL,
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema é de chave estrangeira, está tentando incluir um registro que depende de uma chave estrangeira, mas a tabela dessa chave não tem o registro.

Pelo nome da chave da sua mensagem pode ser tentar incluir uma peça em uma ordem de serviço que não existe.

Caso você veja que absolutamente todos as chaves estejam populadas corretamente em memoria antes de incluir então verifica se ele está incluindo na ordem certa, pode ser que ele esteja tentando incluir uma peça na ordem antes de incluir a ordem.

Comment: mas essa é a ordem.Cadastrar Fornecedor > Cadastrar Peça > Cadastrar Cliente > Cadastrar Veiculo  > Castrar Ordem de Serviço contendo Peça, Cliente, Veiculo

Comment: Então, ou vc cadastra uma peça em uma ordem q não existe ou no momento q cadastra a Ordem de serviço contendo Peça Cliente e Veiculo ela está tentando colocar o relacionamento peça ordem antes da ordem. Esse miolo que você tem que conferir, a mensagem de erro é clara, erro de chave estrangeira, não tem como ser diferente.

Comment: O que recomenda ser feito?

Comment: Coloca na pergunta ali todos os inserts que ele esta fazendo, aí eu consigo te mostrar a ordem a ser executada. As camadas de persistência normalmente tem uma função de log, qual que você está usando? Sabe usar o log dela?